# What does the first <E> signify in public static <E> Set<E> someFunction(){}

Tags: java, generics

Was wondering what is `the first <E> in the <E> Set<E>` signify?

For example in the following code;

I understand it is a public static method with return type `Set<E>`, but had never seen `<E> Set<E>?`

```
public static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> s1, Set<E> s2) {
   Set<E> result = new HashSet<E>(s1);
   result.addAll(s2);
   return result;
}
```

Any help/reference regarding the same would be appreciated.

Comment: It is the type parameter declaration for the method.

Comment: This is called a *generic method*, btw, which may help with finding information on it.

Comment: This is explained in the [generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<E>` signifies to the compiler that the method `union` is a *generic method* that has a generic *type parameter* with the name `E`. Otherwise the compiler would assume that `E` is a type.

**References**

- [Java Language Specification - Generic Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4)

Comment: +1 I don't know if "takes" is the right word. I think "*has* a generic type parameter" is more accurate. Also, these methods are called *typed methods*

Comment: @Bohemian Fixed to say has. Interesting, I've never heard them called typed methods. As far as I know the JLS refers to them only as *generic methods*, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Bohemian could you say it "takes a generic type argument"?

Comment: @Cruncher yes, but that doesn't mean the method has a type. unless of course it's a static method, which this is - if an instance method it could have got the type from the class. A typed method (afaik) declares its own type with a scope of the method only. Even instance methods can be such

Comment: @Bohemian the name for the type would have to be different for an instance method, if you didn't want it to steal it from the instance I presume?

Comment: @Bohemian I think "generic method" is fine: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

The first  is a type parameter that the method accepts.

For example if you call this with Integer it would look like

```
<Integer>Class.union(some Set<Integer>, another Set<Integer>)
```

Then the return type would be a `Set<Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

E before `Set<E>` signifies that future occurrences of E (wherever E is used as a data type name like `Set<E>`) in this method signify a generic type. Refer to Generic Methods(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)